# prevent local storage from saving in other tabs in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi I am new to chrome extension development and I was wondering if there was a way to keep localStorage relative to only the tab.

In other words how do I make it so that if I save a key in one tab that it wont be accessible in another tab.

Here is my code for getting localStorage

```
var prevList: string = localStorage.getItem("prevList");
```

and for setting:

```
localStorage.setItem("prevList", JSON.stringify(prevList));
```

Is there any property about a tab that is unique to that tab that I can store with the data.

For example something like

```
var prevTabProp = localStorage.getItem("tabProp");
if (curTabProp == prevTabProp) {
...
}
```

Taking a shot in the dark.

Comment: `sessionStorage` is locked to a particular tab, though you will lose persistence once the tab is closed.

Comment: Thanks for the response Rob. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage. It seems like the storage does not persist if the user goes to another site within the same tab. Do you know of a workaround to this?

Comment: I don't believe there is a workaround for this, there is no way to lock down localStorage to a particular tab though (on the same domain).

Comment: You can use chrome extension background page to store your tab data instead of localStorage. Send message to the background and save data there by tab id. It won't be saved when you close the browser.

Comment: `localStorage` is accessible for the page itself, across domain. Question is, is that desired? Are you manipulating something that the page will use, or is it just your own settings for the content script and page should not know about them?